# Transfer between aspx.cs and c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Today I have the following question. I would like to develop a thin `aspx.cs` -File. My main problem is that in the `.aspx-View` are a lot of different `Textbox'es` and other user controls. And I would like to write this informations later to a database, so it's important to get all the Values of the controls.

So I could run over it, if I would do something like this:

```
        string a = TextBox1.Text;
        string b = TextBox2.Text;
        .
        .
        .

        SpecialHandlerClass handler = new SpecialHandlerClass(a, b,....);
```

But I think it would be much nicer, if I could Transfer the whole "Aspx-File" to the handler, so that he can handle all the User Controls. That would make the `aspx.cs` file a lot easier to read and edit.

Is this possible?

I'm searching for something like this:

```
SpecialHandlerClass handler = new SpecialHandlerClass(this.Document);
```

So I would get Access to all Controlls of the `.aspx-File` in the Handler.

Comment: That will cause severe performance issues though. But, if you want to, you can try using `Page objPage = this; SpecialHandlerClass handler = new SpecialHandlerClass(objPage);`.

Comment: Moving web control functionality out of the file meant to handle web control functionality will just add an additional layer of complexity. You'll gain nothing trying to make the "thin" file in this manner, as your handle now will be overly complex. Use your aspx.cs fill to communicate with the web controls, it's what it is there for, and then make DTOs between that file and your other layers to have separation of concern. So you move business logic and data access logic, but not web control logic.